# Encontrar o maior numero num ficheiro de texto

Tags: c#, arquivo

Estou a tentar fazer um programa que lê um ficheiro de texto e me diga o maior numero nele.

Eis o que já tenho do código:

```
while (sLine != null)
{
    sLine = objReader.ReadLine();
    if (sLine != null)
        arrText.Add(sLine);
}

objReader.Close();

foreach (string sOutput in arrText)
Console.WriteLine(sOutput);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Esse seu ficheiro de texto possui quais tipos de informações? Apenas números? Possui texto também? As informações estão sendo armazenadas separadas por algum padrão? Mostre um exemplo do seu arquivo por favor?

Comment: este só tem numeros

Answer (score 5):

Você pode ler as linhas do arquivo de uma forma muito mais fácil usando [**`File.ReadAllLines()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx). Este método vai ler o arquivo e criar um *array* onde cada linha do arquivo representa um elemento do *array*.

Depois disso é só converter cada linha para número. O método [**`Select`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) mapeia cada item do *array* de origem (o *array* retornado pelo `ReadAllLines`, neste caso) de acordo com a função passada por parâmetro. A função ali apenas converte cada elemento (`l` representa cada elemento) para número.

Então, ao final disso, tem-se o *array* `numeros` com N elementos (sendo N a quantidade de linhas do arquivo), onde cada elemento é a representação numérica de cada linha do arquivo inicial.

Depois disso é só procurar pelo maior número no *array*.

Este pode ser encontrado usando LINQ, com o método [**`Max`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb534740(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
// using System.Linq; <<-- Inclua isto nos using

var numeros = File.ReadAllLines(caminhoArquivo).Select(l => Convert.ToInt32(l)).ToArray();
var maior = numeros.Max(n => n);
Console.WriteLine($"O maior número no arquivo é {maior}");
```

Pra fins de entendimento, o código acima é equivalente a este

```
var linhas = File.ReadAllLines(caminhoArquivo);

var numeros = new List<int>();
foreach(var l in linhas)
    numeros.Add(Convert.ToInt32(l));

int maior = 0;
foreach(var numero in numeros)
    maior = numero > maior ? numero : maior;

Console.WriteLine($"O maior número no arquivo é {maior}");
```